# Fallo al exportar Excel

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código que utilizo para generar un archivo de excel según un listado HTML:

Tabla HTML

```
    $listado = $Clientes->listarClientes($query);
  if ($lisfra = mysqli_fetch_array($listado)) {
        echo '<table id="tblData" role="grid" style="visibility:hidden"><tbody>';

        do {

            echo '  <tr>
        <td >'.$lisfra['cuenta_contable'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['nombre_comercial'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['cif'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['direccion_principal'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['cp_principal'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['poblacion_principal'].'</td>
        <td >'.$lisfra['provincia_principal'].'</td>
  ';
     echo'
    </tr></form>';
        } while ($lisfra = mysqli_fetch_array($listado));
        echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
```

Para generar el Excel

```
<script>
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Me genera el excel correctamente y se abre, pero al abrirlo me dice:

El formato y la extensión de CLI.xls no coinciden. Puede que el archivo esté dañado o no sea seguro. No lo abra a menos que confíe en su origen. ¿Desea abrirlo de todos modos?

SUpongo que le falta algún dato al archivo pero desconozco cual.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, debes cambiar tu content type (dataType en tu caso) a `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` quedando tu script de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Fuente: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/144372/firefox-muestra-un-mensaje-de-error-al-descargar-el-archivo-xlsx

Comment: Hola, disculpa si te llegó el comentario anterior, llevo poco usando stack. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Necesito saber unos datos, que versión de excel ocupas para abrir el archivo, que sistema operativo, que navegador y un enlace con el documento o ejemplo para ver si tiene algun caracter especial.

Comment: Ok. Excel 2013 con Windows 10, el navegador es Google Chrome y te pongo un ejemplo (Adjunto una linea, tiene mas campos que los que he copiado en la pregunta, los he acortado por no poner un tocho de texto):

20224 5 17/02/2022 4300000147 380 21 79,8 0 0 0 0 0 459,8 Factura del taller Taller de pepe SL 0 0 17/02/2022 0 0 380 0 0

Como nota si le das a si, abrir, lo abre correctamente y lo importa correctamente (El excel generado es para importar en otro programa), la única "molestia" es el aviso, por lo demás funciona todo correctamente.

Comment: Mira, te dejo otros content type para que pruebes y me comentas cual te funcionó. (Estoy 99% seguro que es el MIME  TYPE el que te da problemas)
1-application/vnd.ms-excel
2-application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
3-application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
4-application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12

Comment: Lo he probado con todos y con todos abre, pero sigue saliendo el mismo aviso.

Comment: Podría hacer una ultima prueba por mi por favor, necesito que cambie la extensión de la linea a xlsx quedando así `filename = filename?filename+'.xlsx':'excel_data.xlsx'` y el datatype así: `var dataType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`

Comment: Vale, lo he hecho y directamente me dice: Excel no puede abrir el archivo porque el formato o la extensión de este no son válidos. Compruebe que el archivo no se ha dañado y que la extensión del mismo coincide con el formato del archivo.